# How to Identify the Correct File Type of an Image Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jpeg, file-type, webp

I am trying to determine the file type of an image using JavaScript, but the code I have tried is displaying the file type as 'jpg'. However, when I pass the same file to an external tool like https://exifinfo.org/detail/RjmJqqj8LGEaqOLBEaiyiw, it displays the file type as 'webp', which is the correct file type.
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Identify Image File Type</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="image" src="https://s.alicdn.com/@sc04/kf/H7c1b38f112d044889f7b2c5a2ab914ac3.jpg_100x100xz.jpg">
    <script>
      const image = document.getElementById('image');
      image.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const width = image.naturalWidth;
        const height = image.naturalHeight;
        const url = new URL(image.src);
        const extension = url.pathname.split('.').pop();
        console.log(`The file type is ${extension}`);
      });
      image.addEventListener('error', () => {
        console.log('The file is not a valid image');
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried using a third-party library, 'file-type' to determine correct file type. Here is the code I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Identify Image File Type</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="image">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-type/dist/index.umd.js"></script>
    <script>
      const imageUrl = 'https://s.alicdn.com/@sc04/kf/H7c1b38f112d044889f7b2c5a2ab914ac3.jpg_100x100xz.jpg';
      fetch(imageUrl)
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(buffer => {
          const fileType = window.fileType.fromBuffer(new Uint8Array(buffer));
          const image = document.getElementById('image');
          image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const width = image.naturalWidth;
            const height = image.naturalHeight;
            console.log(`The file type is ${fileType.ext}`);
          });
          image.addEventListener('error', () => {
            console.log('The file is not a valid image');
          });
          const objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer], { type: fileType.mime }));
          image.src = objectUrl;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(`Error fetching image: ${error.message}`);
        });
    </script>
  </body
```

> 

But it gives error:
GET https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-type/dist/index.umd.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
Error fetching image: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fromBuffer')

Can someone please guide me on how to correctly determine the file type of an image in JavaScript? The ideal output for the image in question should be 'webp'."

Comment: There's a separate method for using [that library in the browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type

It's on the JS Docs? Always look into the JS Docs... MDN is the best JS Docs. Use "site:developer.mozilla.org js file type", or anything you want to search, it's useful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file-type-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type-checker) library instead:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Identify Image File Type</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="image">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/file-type-checker@1.0.4/dist/index.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const imageUrl = 'https://s.alicdn.com/@sc04/kf/H7c1b38f112d044889f7b2c5a2ab914ac3.jpg_100x100xz.jpg';
      fetch(imageUrl)
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(buffer => {
          const detectedFile = window.fileTypeChecker.detectFile(buffer);
          const image = document.getElementById('image');
          image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const width = image.naturalWidth;
            const height = image.naturalHeight;
            console.log(`The file type is ${detectedFile.extension}`);
          });
          image.addEventListener('error', () => {
            console.log('The file is not a valid image');
          });
          const objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([buffer], { type: fileType.mime }));
          image.src = objectUrl;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(`Error fetching image: ${error.message}`);
        });
    </script>
  </body
```

If you want to validate if the file type is an image, you can also use 'validateFileType' method:

```
window.fileTypeChecker.validateFileType(buffer, ["png", "gif", "jpeg"]); // Returns true if the file is an image from the accepted list
```